# Where to Find Historical Earning Event (Quarterly Figures Dissemination) Dates?

Tags: equities, historical-data, fundamentals

I am looking for a data source / database that holds historical (10 years, better 20 years) dates of US and European stocks:

I need the **historical date** when the quarterly (or annual) fundamental data of that company was published in the past.

So in short terms: I need the historical ***Earning Event*** dates.

Solutions like Reuters or Bloomberg would possibly be too expensive... :-(

Comment: Take a look at [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html).

Comment: thanks for that hint. But as far as I know, EDGAR / SEC is only for US companies, isn't it?

Comment: 4-traders does have them, but only for one year, as it seems: (http://www.4-traders.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/) . Yahoo finance seems to have it, too, but I am unsure about the data quality.

Comment: you can look at exchanges where the firms are listed. firms need to notify the exchanges for any event. although i'm sure if you will find any API

Comment: if Reuters or Bloomberg are too expensive then you will have a hard time. There are some high quality historical datasets but would be even more expensive. Are you working in academia, industry or trading for yourself ?

Comment: trading for myself

Answer (score -1):

The **publication date** differs from the **statement date**. If the statement date is '201**6**-12-31', the publication date could be '201**7**-02-15'. Sometimes, thera are *restatements* (=annual report is republished with corrected new numbers) where publication date is '201**7**-02-15' for statement date '201**5**-12-31'. Both dates are published in Reuters databases. If this is too expensive, try to find this on Quandl (I'm not sure if they have both dates).